# How to exclude certain import on specific architecture while building GoLang application

Tags: oracle, go, build

I faced a very specific use-case in building go application related to existence of ORACLE libraries on specific architecture. To be specific here is a go code:

```
import (
   "fmt"

   // oracle drivers
   _ "github.com/mattn/go-oci8"
   _ "gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4"

   // go-sqlite driver
   _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
...
)
```

Now, since on ARM I do not have ORACLE libs I would like to skip loading oracle drivers in my build, but on Linux since I do have ORACLE libs I would like to keep oracle drivers. Such that I do not want to change the code but somehow build should figure out that in one case it can't load ORACLE libs and the build should only use sqlite3, while on another architecture both should be linked to the executable.

How I can address this use-case? Using `//go:build !arm64` does not help since it will skip entirely arm build which is not what I want, i.e. I want to build on arm but only use sqlite driver.

Moreover, I presented the case when I want to try out different oracle drivers with my code and it is yet another level of complexity. How to instruct build to use one vs another based on condition if I do have specific libs.

If any other tools can be used, e.g. Makefile, or plain unix awk, etc. I would appreciate to know any tricks you can come up with. I am considering using Makefile where I can comment out the lines with oracle driver, but it will modify the file. Of course, I can do these steps:

- use Makefile
- use unix tool, e.g. awk, to comment out oracle driver lines through my codebase
- build executable
- use unix tool to put back oracle driver lines

So, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Build constrains are on a per file basis: You have to separate the blank import into their own file.

Comment: The blank imports (the `import _ "gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4"`) are there for their side effects _only_. Your Go code doesn't (actually cannot) use these packages. It's thus fine to put then in a otherwise empty file and delete them here.

Comment: If I put imports into separate file with `//go:build linux` directive my linker still tries to pick up ORACLE `-lclntsh` and complains about it. So, most likely, `go build` compiler step is fine but not the linker. How I can resolve that?

Comment: If you need different arguments to the linker (assuming you are go build'ing with -ldflags) you must resort to smth. like a Makefile or a bash script and invoke go build differently depending on the availability of the Oracle driver.

Comment: I would put platform specific code in dedicated files, and call them `defs_linux.go.in`, `defs_win.go.in`. Then do a `configure` step which copies the relevant `*.in` file to `defs.go`.